# Persist Cordova platforms folder for faster CI builds

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, continuous-integration, ionic3

Best practice for Ionic/Cordova projects is to not check in the `platforms/` and `plugins/` folders into SCM and Cordova will take care of bootstrapping all required dependencies on the first build. While this works fine for developers it significantly slows down builds on a CI server.

For example, we run a MacMini as build slave and `cordova prepare` takes around 10 minutes to complete (for two platforms) out of a total build time of 12 minutes (most of the other 2 minutes is spend on `npm install`). Now, I already tried to simply cache the `platforms/` and `plugins/`folders between build jobs. However, as I need to dynamically update the bundleId/package name and app name to distinguish builds for different environments, this results in an error that Cordova cannot dynamically update this data.

I was wondering if anyone has experienced similar issues and would be interested in which ways you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Cordova installing the plugins is really the slow part of the build. Caching the `plugins/` folder between builds seems to work and cut the build time in half.